# Python 3.7 Input data not recognized by loop

Tags: loops, input

copy and past this code in your IDE and run it. The output will be: 
(1, 3, 4)
yes
(1, 3, 4)
[list of all combos]
Done

However if you comment out the N = tuple statement and uncomment the N = input statement.
Then run it you will be asked to enter a (tuple) with 3 numbers in the range 1-5 in ascending order. When you then run that I would think you should get the same output but NO! For some reason even though the tuple is correct and prints out as such it for some reason is not recognized in the loop and it bypasses it. Thus the print statement YES does not print. output is:
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 4)
[list of all combos]
Done

So why is this and what can I do to fix it?

from itertools import combinations

```
N = (1, 3, 4)  # N is tuple with 3 numbers
#  N = input('Enter (tuple)')
print(N)

combos = [numbers for numbers in combinations(range(1, 6), 3)]
for numbers in combos:
    if N == numbers:
        print('yes') 

print(N)
print(combos)
print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your issue here is that when you uncomment the input line, N gets set as a string and not as a tuple, as input automatically sets whatever it gets to a string. One solution would be this:

`N1 = int(input("Enter the first number"))
N2 = int(input("Enter the second number"))
N3 = int(input("Enter the third number"))
N = (N1, N2, N3)`

Comment: Does not work. on  the first number entered it loops directly to end bypasses the next two inputs.

Comment: plug it into the code and see for yourself what it does.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show exactly what the code you have written is?

Comment: did it just make  sure to do the  import above it.

Comment: Hey sorry it does work I just made a typo after going back and giving it a second look, Thank you.